# Is there a way to bind a key to a function so that it executes 1 time and removes the binding?

Tags: emacs

For example, \C-c l writes (lambda () ()) and puts my cursor in the first empty parenthesis. I want it so clicking enter jumps to center of second empty parenthesis.

Comment: Did you mean *pressing* enter? Clicking is what you do with a mouse.

Comment: Why do you want the binding removed after the first use? Does your coding style only allow for one lambda per source file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to do what you want, but before jumping through those hoops, perhaps it'd be easier to look at a package that might suit your needs.

Have you thought of trying [yasnippet](http://code.google.com/p/yasnippet/)?  It basically does what you want, it inserts a template and (upon pressing TAB) will jump you from field to field until the template is filled in.

If you still want to roll your own, you probably should at least look at yasnippet to see how the key bindings are handled.